# Activity с горизонтальной и вертикальной прокруткой android wear

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-wear

Есть задача сделать экран с горизонтальной прокруткой и вертикальной одновременно. Должно получиться что то типа этого. Т.е. идет экран со словом и переводом -> свайп вверх -> попадаем на экран с примерами -> свайп вниз  -> попадаем обратно на экран со словом и переводом -> свайп влево -> попадает на экран со следующим словом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю тут скорее всего нужно ViewPager использовать, но я пока знаю как можно сделать прокрутку только в одном направлении. А как можно реализовать нужный мне вариант!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте GridViewPager http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.html

Пример использования - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-GridViewPager

Comment: попробовал запустить  этот пример на телефоне установилось и запустилось, а на часах  почему то нет, не знаете почему такое может быть?